# How to fix large confidence intervals in a forest plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cox-regression, r-forestplot

I am trying to create a forest plot of several Confidence intervals derived from Cox regression analysis. The plot turned out good at first however when I added new data with large confidence intervals the forest plot now looks very messy. Is there a way to make the plot less messy for example to cut the x axsis at a certain value and make large confidence intervals go outside the scale? Very thankful for any help.

I've tried log transforming the data, however this did not solve the problem.

Example data (where condition is a marker and Compartment is grouping variable).

```
Condition   RiskRatio   UpperLimit  LowerLimit  Compartment
8   0,939   1,363   0,647   Tumour
9   0,484   0,996   0,236   Tumour
10  1,124   1,632   0,775   Tumour
11  12,616  56,146  2,835   Tumour
12  0,981   3,092   0,311   Tumour
13  0,875   1,272   0,603   Tumour
8   1,264   0,871   1,836   Stroma
9   1,054   2,02    0,55    Stroma
10  0,957   1,388   0,659   Stroma
11  1,34    5,431   0,33    Stroma
12  0,683   4,896   0,095   Stroma
13  0,743   1,081   0,511   Stroma
8   1,129   1,639   0,777   1tot
9   0,665   0,391   1,13    1tot
10  0,972   1,411   0,67    1tot
11  2,441   6,648   0,896   1tot
12  0,981   3,092   0,311   1tot
13  0,806   1,171   0,555   1tot
```

```
p = ggplot(data=RR_data,
           aes(x = Compartment,y = RiskRatio, ymin = LowerLimit, ymax = UpperLimit ))+
  geom_pointrange(aes(col=Compartment))+ theme_classic() +
  geom_hline(aes(fill=Compartment),yintercept =1, linetype=2)+
  xlab('Immune cell population')+ ylab("Hazard Ratio (95% Confidence Interval)")+
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=LowerLimit, ymax=UpperLimit,col=Compartment),width=0.5,cex=0.5)+ 
  facet_wrap(~Condition,strip.position="left",nrow=9,scales = "free_y") +
  theme(plot.title=element_text(size=10,face="bold"),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_text(face="bold"),
        axis.title=element_text(size=10,face="bold"),
        strip.text.y = element_text(hjust=0,vjust = 1,angle=180,face="bold"))+
        scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2,2.25,2.5,3,3.5))+
  coord_flip()
p
```

Comment: Take a look at `coord_cartesian()`. It lets you zoom the plot without removing the data points.

Comment: You could display the hazard ratio on a log - scale, e.g. add `scale_y_log10` or `scale_y_continuous(trans = "log2")`